# What impact does the order of a multiindex index have?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

There are many questions on SO about how to reorder the a multiindex index.
Does the order have any material difference in performance or otherwise?

Why would someone reorder the index (other then for presentation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordered indexes are useful together with `loc` when subseting data frames on some categorical variable. For example, for the following data frame

```
import pandas as pd
index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
x = np.arange(6)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x}, 
                  index = pd.Categorical(index, categories=['a', 'b', 'c'], ordered=True))
```

`df.loc['b':'c']` gives error, while

```
df = df.sort_index()
df.loc['b':'c']
```

gives correctly selected rows.

```
   x
b  1
b  4
c  2
c  5
```